# bash set -x Non English character showing

Tags: linux, bash, shell

run

```
set -x
echo 中文
echo english
```

It shows

```
+ echo $'\344\270\255\346\226\207'
中文
+ echo english
english
```

how to make it show + echo 中文 $ rather than + echo $'\344\270\255\346\226\207'?

Comment: Why? The debug mode shows the byte representation of your UTF characters

Comment: To be more explicit, if you don't know the character encoding at every step of the process, seeing the individual bytes is quite valuable, and the decoded form is ambiguous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how to show + echo 中文 $ rather than + echo $'\344\270\255\346\226\207'?

It is not possible without changing bash sources.

> how to **make it** show + echo 中文 $ rather than + echo $'\344\270\255\346\226\207'?

Write a patch for bash sources and implement your own behavior that will use this representation. There is no other way, as `set -x` output comes from within bash itself (except that prefix `+` is configurable with `PS4`). The output from `set -x` is produced [in print_cmd.c xtrace_print_word_list()](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/f3a35a2d601a55f337f8ca02a541f8c033682247/print_cmd.c#L542).

Answer (score 5):

Possibly depends on Bash's version, operating system and locale environment:

```sh
$ echo 中文
+ echo 中文
中文
$ echo "$BASH_VERSION"
+ echo '5.0.17(1)-release'
5.0.17(1)-release
$ locale
+ locale
LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=fr:de_DE:en
LC_CTYPE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_TIME=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_NAME=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```